# execl() find command c

Tags: c, linux, find, exec

I want to execute to the shell the find command to print me only the *.c files
and then return the string with the files and print it to stdout. 
I am using pipes to do that. When i try to run i always get `find failed: No such file or directory`

I think the problem is the path.
the path that i should give it is `home/username/Downloads` in case i want to print all the *.c files that exist in my Downloads folder??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char ** argv){
   int fds[2];
   char buffer[4096];

   if(pipe(fds) == -1){
      perror("pipe creation failed");
      exit(1);
   }

   switch (fork()){

    case 0://child
       close(fds[0]);
       execl("usr/bin/find","find","home/username/Downloads", "-name \"*.c\" -print0",NULL);
       perror("find failed");
       exit(20);
       break;

      case -1: //fork failure
       perror("fork failure");
       exit(1);

      default: //parent
       close(fds[1]); //close stdin so only can do stdout
       int size= read(fds[0],buffer, 4096);
       printf("%s",buffer);
   }

   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: argv[0] is the program name not the first argument to the program

Comment: ok you're right. i will edit now

Comment: You should use the glob() function. See also readdir() or stat()

Comment: Shouldn't there be a slash in front of `home/username/Downloads`? Or is `home` a directory inside the one where your program is running?

Comment: @Sevauk i would like to learn how to execute linux commands through a program and get its return. I know what `readdir()` and `stat()` does.

Comment: @squeamish the same in front of usr/bin/find

Comment: @squeamishossifrage when i try `/` the same error again. no my program runs from eclipse workspace. I want the program to find the *.c in a specified directory

Comment: You also might like to take look a `popen()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd propose to pass seperate arguments as seperate arguments:

```
    execl("/usr/bin/find", "find", 
      "/home/username/Downloads", 
      "-name",
      "*.c", /* As no shell is invoked no quotation marks are needed to protect the *. */
      "-print0",  
      (char *) NULL);
```

Comment: can you help me also printing the results?

Answer (score 2):

There's a leading slash missing in front of usr/bin/find, so find only be executed when the working directory is /

Comment: use dup() or dup2() to redirect find's stdout